# How to run multiple python files in a folder one after another and how to generate single html report?

Tags: python, api, report, pytest

Each time I run these files in the terminal this form one after another :

```
pytest home.py
pytest work.py
pytest office.py
pytest road.py
pytest flight.py

.
.
.
```

(I have provided general file names here)

This process takes a lot of time.

Is it possible to run these files together one after another through any script..?

If possible, then how..?

Please provide the code if possible...

I came to know through a few sites that, using bash script we can do that.

I don't know how to implement it.

If you can suggest any other method, even that would be helpful.

And I need to generate a report for each file.

If I am running the individual file, then I can generate HTML file using --HTML--report.html. But I want to run all the files at a time and need to generate only one report. For every execution, it should generate a new report using a timestamp.

If somebody could tell me how I can overcome this, It would be helpful.

Comment: You added pytest as a tag - does that mean you use pytest? Please provide a bit more information what are these scripts (are they tests?) and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi..Those are all pytest files and inside of every file we have multiple test methods.In every file nearly 8-10 test functions are there , So totally i have 150 test functions are there from all the pytest files. I want to execute all of them with in one command and i want to generate html report as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your test files to `test_xxx.py` or `xx_test.py`, then run pytest in the root directory of your test files.

Pytest will discover all tests in these files and generate a single report for them. You may check [how pytest discovers tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery) to get a better understanding.

If you want to add the timestamp to your report file name, you can try to add the `date` variable, if you are in Linux:

```
pytest -v -s --junitxml=results$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').xml
```

or, if you have installed `pytest-html` and want to create an html report:

```
pytest -v -s --html=report$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')).html
```

You can call this in your shell script, of course:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m pytest -v -s --html=report$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').html
```

Or, if you want to call it from another Python script for some reason:

```
import pytest
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
pytest.main(['-v', '-s', f'--junitxml=report{now:%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}.xml'])
```

Comment: yes bean , it is working now. parallelly i want to generate html report for every execution. Now i am using pytest -v -s --html=report.html bash command. Is there any way to implement this report generation based on timestamp using script or bash command ?

Comment: I added it to the answer (untested, as I'm under Windows).

Comment: Thanks Bean!!!! Is there any other way to implement this using script itself. M planning to generate html report using script only. Can you help me on this if you have any idea

Comment: I don't know what you mean - can't you run that in a script?

Comment: I mean if i want to trigger that entire suite , i have to open terminal and i want to give  pytest -v -s --html=report$(date).html test.py . Instead of this can we develop a script to generate html report.So without giving any commands if we execute that particular file it should generate html report also

Comment: Still don't understand. Why not write that line in your script? Do you have some special requirements for your scripts? Are these standard shell scripts or something else? Maybe you mean a Python script?

Comment: python -m pytest -v -s --html=report$(date).html ===> This command is not generating report with date format.                                                                      
pytest -v -s --html=.\reports\html_reports\report$(datetime.datetime.now).html  ==> I tried with this command also.We are seeing report with this name report$(datetime.datetime.now).html

Comment: $(date) may not work due to illegal path characters - I updated the answer to add a format (still untested, as I'm under Windows, but you may look this up, if this doesn't work). `datetime.datetime.now` is a Python call - you cannot put that into a bash command.